# Gnuplot vertical gradient on boxes depending of a value?

Tags: gnuplot, linear-gradients

Is this possible in gnuplot?

How more energie how harder the color, look the example.

[image]

[image]

```
plot for [i=1:16] file u 1:($10/i):((i*2)*1048576) w boxes lc rgb variable notitle.
```

This is what I have now, this might be a possibility? The first example was an Excel graph.

Comment: No, this is not possible with gnuplot.

Comment: Yes, that could be indeed a useable solution. You could also add this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finaly i have for me the perfect, and . . i think a very nice solution.
First the plot and after that the correspondenting script.
[image]

```
The highlights are;    
maks = STATS_max_y  
min  = STATS_max_x  
afgenomen = gebruikt-zon  

set palette defined (-(min) "#D30000", 0 "#00F000", .1 "#FFF900", (maks) "#FF0700")

plot for [i=51:1:-1] file u 1:(($10/51)*i):(($10/51)*i) w boxes lc palette  notitle,\
                     file u 1:10 w boxes fill empty  notitle,\
```

For all the examples that i have made look on my site: http://ccvd.eu/Energie.html