# Gnuplot with both color and xtic from data file

Tags: colors, gnuplot, label

I want to make a bar plot, using gnuplot, with values from column 3, xtic labels from column 2, and color from column 4 of my data file. The file looks like:

```
0   "13 Sep"    2400.18     "blue"
1   "13 Oct"    440.86      "blue"
2   "13 Nov"    867.03      "blue"
3   "13 Dec"    -247.32     "red"
4   "14 Jan"    -3457.56    "red"
5   "14 Feb"    666.94      "blue"
```

Currently, I plot with the following command,

```
plot "output.txt" using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes
```

and the plot has the correct tic labels in the x-axis and all the bars are colored red. What I would like to do it to get the bar color from the file, or alternatively have a smooth color palette from blue to red, going through white.

I have tried a lot of different suggestions that I've found searching the internet but with no success. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a linecolor based on your data, you can use `linecolor variable`. In that case you must give a line type index as additional column.

Your data file is somewhat redundant. You don't need to have the first column, you have always access to the row number as `column(0)`. The color can be derived from the value sign:

```
"13 Sep"    2400.18     
"13 Oct"    440.86      
"13 Nov"    867.03      
"13 Dec"    -247.32     
"14 Jan"    -3457.56    
"14 Feb"    666.94
```

The script is:

```
set style fill solid noborder
set xzeroaxis lt -1 lw 2
set boxwidth 0.9 relative
plot "output.txt" using 0:2:($2 < 0 ? 1 : 3):xtic(1) with boxes linecolor variable t ''
```

with the result (version 4.6.3):

[image]

You could also use `linecolor rgb variable`, `linecolor palette` etc.

If you want to color the boxes as a mixture of red/blue and white, based on according to their values, you can do it as follows:

```
set style fill solid border lt -1
set xzeroaxis lt -1 lw 2
set boxwidth 0.9 relative
unset key

stats "output.txt" using 2 nooutput
set palette defined (STATS_min 'red', 0 'white', STATS_max 'blue')
set autoscale cbfix

plot "output.txt" using 0:2:2:xtic(1) with boxes linecolor palette
```

with the result:

[image]

Getting a gradient inside the boxes is more involved and needs some tricking, see [Gnuplot vertical gradient on boxes depending of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20960054/2604213).

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for. The last solution required gnuplot 4.6 though. I had version 4.4 but now I'm running 4.6.